# controlling the wlServerContext in mobilefirst ant builds

Tags: android, ios, ant, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to build the MobileFirst artifacts using `ant`, but I can't get the `wlServerContext` to come out right in either the `wlclient.properties` file (Android) or the `worklight.plist` file (iOS).
In both cases it comes out as `/`, where I want `/MyProject/` - which is what `mfp build` manages to produce.

Here is the `ant` file I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="mfp-ant-build" basedir="/Users/sean/Development/MyProject">
  <taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/public/worklight-ant-builder.jar" />
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>
  <target name="mfp-ant-build">
    <war-builder projectfolder="${basedir}" classesFolder="bin/classes" destinationfolder="../build/dist/servers/mfp-ant-build-local/tmp" warfile="../build/dist/servers/mfp-ant-build-local/MyProject.war" />
    <app-builder nativeProjectPrefix="MyProject" applicationFolder="apps/MyApp" worklightserverhost="https://myserver/" outputFolder="../build/dist/servers/mfp-ant-build-local" />
  </target>
</project>
```

What more do I need to do?

FWIW:

```
$ mfp --version
7.0.0.00.20150608-1402
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the context root (the missing piece in your attempt) is supposed to be part of the `worklightserverhost` property.

Based on the [Ant builder task documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_buld_deploy_apps.html) (look at the very bottom for an example), here's a sample Ant task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir=".">
  <taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/public/worklight-ant-builder.jar"/>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>
  <target name="myTestTarget">
    <app-builder
        worklightserverhost="http://localhost:10080/demoproject"
        applicationFolder="apps/demoapp"
        environments="android,iphone"
        nativeProjectPrefix="demoproject"
        outputFolder="~/Desktop"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: I've got both the war builder and app builder entries in the target - it does `<war-builder>` then `<ant-builder>`.
It seemed to be working like this before I started looking more closely and noticed `wlServerContext` not being set. Are you saying they should be completely separate ant targets?

Comment: You're right, I'm actually not sure how I missed the app-builder line there. :) Well, you could try separately. Maybe that's that.

Comment: Running the `<war-builder>` first followed by the `<app-builder>` makes no difference, the `wlServerContext` is still `/` not `/MyProject/`.

Comment: and if you try "/MyProject/"?

Comment: `/MyProject/`, as the `nativeProjectPrefix`?
Same result: `wlServerContext = /` (in `wlclient.properties`)

Comment: Okay, is this a native project or a hybrid project?

Comment: It is a hybrid project.

Comment: @N2O, I think that you need to give the full server address, including the context. For example: localhost:10080/mycontext. I edited the answer accordingly.